# Seeking an unpublished manuscript by Tetsuro Okuyama

Tags: rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra, kt.k-theory-and-homology, projective-modules

Several papers in representation theory attribute the notion of relatively projective modules to Tetsuro Okuyama's manuscript "A generalization of projective covers of modules over finite group algebras." I haven't been able to find this by googling. Can anyone point me to a copy (or send me one)?

Thanks!